# redirect sql query results to a .log file

Tags: mysql

I have a c-shell scrip that connects to a mysql database database through and invokes a sql script which in turn invokes another sql script to run a query and return a report

```
#!/bin/csh 

set MYSQL=${MYSQL_HOME}/mysql 
set REPORT=${CLEADM_HOME}/Scripts/DataValidation/EOreport.sql 
${MYSQL} ${CLEDBUSER} <${REPORT}
```

Then within the eoreport.sql I invoke another script like so

Source IERSs.sql

and finally in the IERSs.sql script i need to log the results to a log file but it is not working

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB_EARTHORIENTATIONPARAMETER_UI 
INTO OUTFILE '/vobs/tools/Scripts /results.log'
```

This is not working. All i see is the results of the query printed to the xterm(im using tcsh on solaris and the database is mysql client). Am i missing something?

i have even done research about the tee command that is supposed to pipe in you input and output i to the file that you specify as follows

tee /vobs/tools/Scripts/DataValidation/results.txt

```
SELECT * FROM TB_EARTHORIENTATIONPARAMETER_UI;
```

but this still outputs results to the screen and leaves my result.txt file empty. What am i missing ?

Comment: why do i need to improve that?

Comment: because that's how you said "thanks for helping me" and the person receive points for that

Comment: ok i understand ...but i thought you only accpet what actually worked and became a solution for your problem

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB_EARTHORIENTATIONPARAMETER_UI 
INTO OUTFILE '/vobs/tools/Scripts /results.log'
```

you have a extra space between scripts and /, try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TB_EARTHORIENTATIONPARAMETER_UI 
INTO OUTFILE '/vobs/tools/Scripts/results.log'
```

Also you said :

"leaves my result.txt file empty."  and you are trying to write a result.log file

Comment: i fixed this space and nothing happens. I originally said results.txt because it isn't creating a .log file and so i created a results.txt file in that directory and it still remains empty. How about the tee command in mysql. Am i using it correctly?

Comment: now it gives me a new error. It says the sql file IERSsql has access denied for the user account that i have logged in with for mysql yet before it was running the query just fine

Comment: i have permissions to write to results.txt and also permissions to write into that directory

Comment: when i remove the statement (INTO OUTFILE /) it runs well but displays the reuslts of the query to the xterm...

Comment: Sounds like you have a rights issue .. your account you are using might not have access to that file location, and forgive me as its been a minute, but i THINK there might be a setting you have to change to "allow" it, but I think thats for a specific pre-defined directory, but long story short, can you try to use another mysql account with more access, OR change the output location to something further up the food chain.